# Hire a Pilot & Rent a plane or need to purchase

Tags: rental

I am interested in buying a plane and hiring a pilot on an as needed basis for flights. Is that possible?
Before making the decision to purchase, is it possible to rent a plane and separately hire a pilot? I expect to average 4-5 flight days per month.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, what you are asking about is called private carriage.  If you buy an airplane it's not much different than hiring a chauffeur to drive you in your personal car. The pilot would just need a Commercial Pilot Certificate, and be rated and endorsed for whatever type aircraft you buy. Your insurance company would likely have some additional requirements for total flight hours, time in model, instrument rating, etc.

Regarding the rental part of your question, it would be far easier and better to rent a plane and pilot from the same outfit. Primarily because *nobody will rent an airplane to you as a non-pilot*.  A lot of places that rent planes also offer private charter service using small GA aircraft.  There's no need or benefit to complicating things for yourself and others by going against an established business model to "separately hire" your own pilot to fly a rental.

Comment: The first paragraph is what most corporate flight departments do.  The second paragraph falls under Part 135 charter operations if you want to do more research.